# Add custom class to selected text in tinymce V5

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm trying to implement inside tinymce a custom button, that when clicked, would add a class around the selected text.

I've tried this :

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('fwnormal', {
    text: 'N',
    class: 'nongras'
});
```

But it doesn't work, I get an error `Could not find valid *strict* value for "onAction"`

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/

Use the codes like these:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mytextarea",
  tinymce options: ... ,

  toolbar: "add_class",

  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on("init", function(e) {

      tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register("new_class", {
        selector: "p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6", // choose elements
        classes: "myclass",
        styles: { ... },
        attributes: { ... },
      });  // close formatter.register

    });  // close editor.on init

    editor.ui.registry.addButton("add_class", {
      tooltip: "new class",
      icon: "edit-block", // look editor-icon-identifiers page
      onAction: function() {
        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply("new_class");
      }
    }); // close registry.addButton

  }, // close setup function

}); // close tinymce.init
```

Or try these codes:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mytextarea",
  tinymce options: ... ,

  toolbar: "add_class",

  setup: function(editor) {

    editor.ui.registry.addButton("add_class", {
      tooltip: "new class",
      icon: "edit-block", // look editor-icon-identifiers page
      onAction: function() {
        var element = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
        tinymce.activeEditor.dom.setAttrib(element, "class", "myclass");
      }
    }); // close registry.addButton

  }, // close setup function

}); // close tinymce.init
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom classes are set in the style_formats https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that (as well as literally every single thing in their doc and all answers I could find on SO), couldn't get it to work. If you know how to do that then some code would be nice, or a working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

example

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  style_formats: [
    {title: 'Class name', selector: 'p', classes: 'myclass'} 
  ]
});
```

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Slhaab

Comment: Tested, this does absolutely nothing. (why the need to give a second answer? you could just edit your first answer)